# why doesn't drawable apears on Button?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am a newbie in Java-Android developing.
I want to add this drawable on a view like button's background 
but it doesn't draw anything.

This is my background **drawable_shining.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#000"
            android:centerColor="#111"
            android:startColor="#000"
            android:angle="45"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#000"
            android:gradientRadius="100"
            android:startColor="#555"
            android:type="radial" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list> 
[here is code and layout][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to documentation [layer-list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) is a drawable object that manages an array of other drawables. Each drawable in the list is drawn in the order of the list—the last drawable in the list is drawn on top.

Each drawable is represented by an  element inside a single  element.

in your code, write each `<shape>` in `<item>` tag. Your final code will be look like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#000"
            android:gradientRadius="100"
            android:startColor="#333"
            android:type="radial" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#000"
            android:gradientRadius="100"
            android:startColor="#333"
            android:type="radial" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use same format like below code :

Reference : [angrytools](http://angrytools.com/android/button/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:radius="14dp"
/>
<gradient
android:angle="45"
android:centerX="35%"
android:centerColor="#47A891"
android:startColor="#E8E8E8"
android:endColor="#000000"
android:type="linear"
/>
<padding
android:left="0dp"
android:top="0dp"
android:right="0dp"
android:bottom="0dp"
/>
<size
android:width="270dp"
android:height="60dp"
/>
<stroke
android:width="3dp"
android:color="#878787"
/>
</shape>
```